# Using numpy.where() to iterate through a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, where-clause

There's something about `numpy.where()` I do not understand:

Let's say I have a 2D numpy ndarray:

```
import numpy as np
twodim =  np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],  [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1, 12],  [17, 3, 15, 16], [17, 3, 18, 18]])
```

Now, would like to create a function which "checks" this numpy array for a variety of conditions.

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  1,  1, 12],
       [17,  3, 15, 16],
       [17,  3, 18, 18]])
```

For example, which entries in this array have (A) even numbers (B) greater than 7 (C) divisible by 3?

I would like to use `numpy.where()` for this, and iterate through each entry of this array, finally finding the elements which match all conditions (if such an entry exists):

```
   even_entries = np.where(twodim % 2 == 0)
   greater_seven = np.where(twodim > 7 )
   divisible_three = np.where(twodim % 3 == 0)
```

How does one do this? I am not sure how to iterate through Booleans...

I could access the indices of the matrix (i,j) via

```
np.argwhere(even_entries)
```

We could do something like

```
import numpy as np
twodim =  np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],  [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1, 12],  [17, 3, 15, 16], [17, 3, 18, 18]])
even_entries = np.where(twodim % 2 == 0)
greater_seven = np.where(twodim > 7 )
divisible_three = np.where(twodim % 3 == 0)
for row in even_entries:
    for item in row:
        if item: #equivalent to `if item == True`
                for row in greater_seven:
                    for item in row:
                        if item: #equivalent to `if item == True`
                            for row in divisible_three:
                                for item in row:
                                    if item: #equivalent to `if item == True`
                                        # something like print(np.argwhere())
```

Any advice?

EDIT1: Great ideas below. As @hpaulj mentions "Your tests produce a boolean matrix of the same shape as twodim"
This is a problem I'm running into as I toy around---not all conditionals produce matrices the same shape as my starting matrix. For instance, let's say I'm comparing whether the array element has a matching array to the left or right (i.e. horizontally)

```
twodim[:, :-1] == twodim[:, 1:]
```

That results in a (5,3) Boolean array, whereas our original matrix is a (5,4) array

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

If we do the same vertically, that results in a (4,4) Boolean array, whereas the original matrix is (5,4)

```
twodim[:-1] == twodim[1:]

array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

If we wished to know which entries have *both* vertical and horizontal pairs, it is non-trivial to figure out which dimension we are in.

Comment: Don't use `where`. I don't know why new NumPy users keep using it, but it's rarely a good idea. You could get this done much easier by working with the boolean masks directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests produce a boolean matrix of the same shape as `twodim`:

```
In [487]: mask3 = twodim%3==0
In [488]: mask3
Out[488]: 
array([[False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

As other answers noted you can combine tests logically - with and and or.

`np.where` is the same as `np.nonzero` (in this use), and just returns the coordinates of the True values - as a tuple of 2 arrays.

```
In [489]: np.nonzero(mask3)
Out[489]: 
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

`argwhere` returns the same values, but as a transposed 2d array.

```
In [490]: np.argwhere(mask3)
Out[490]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

Both the `mask` and `tuple` can be used to index your array directly:

```
In [494]: twodim[mask3]
Out[494]: array([ 3,  6, 12,  3, 15,  3, 18, 18])
In [495]: twodim[np.nonzero(mask3)]
Out[495]: array([ 3,  6, 12,  3, 15,  3, 18, 18])
```

The `argwhere` can't be used directly for indexing, but may be more suitable for iteration, especially if you want the indexes as well as the values:

```
In [496]: for i,j in np.argwhere(mask3):
   .....:     print(i,j,twodim[i,j])
   .....:     
0 2 3
1 1 6
2 3 12
3 1 3
3 2 15
4 1 3
4 2 18
4 3 18
```

The same thing with `where` requires a `zip`:

```
for i,j in zip(*np.nonzero(mask3)): print(i,j,twodim[i,j])
```

BUT in general in `numpy` we try to avoid iteration.  If you can use `twodim[mask]` directly your code will be much faster.

Logical combinations of the boolean masks are easier to produce than combinations of the `where` indices.  To use the indices I'd probably resort to `set` operations (union, intersect, difference).

---

As for a reduced size test, you have to decide how that maps on to the original array (and other tests).  e.g.

A (5,3) mask (difference between columns):

```
In [505]: dmask=np.diff(twodim, 1).astype(bool)
In [506]: dmask
Out[506]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

It can index 3 columns of the original array

```
In [507]: twodim[:,:-1][dmask]
Out[507]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  1,  6,  7,  1, 17,  3, 15, 17,  3])
In [508]: twodim[:,1:][dmask]
Out[508]: array([ 2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8, 12,  3, 15, 16,  3, 18])
```

It can also be combined with 3 columns of another mask:

```
In [509]: dmask & mask3[:,:-1]
Out[509]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

It is still easier to combine tests in the boolean array form than with `where` indices.

Comment: @ hpaulj 
"Your tests produce a boolean matrix of the same shape as twodim"
This is a problem I'm running into as I toy around---not all conditionals produce matrices the same shape as my starting matrix. See comments above in the EDIT

Comment: I added your example.

Comment: Thanks. There's something I'm still not following above. Our original matrix is (5,4), and `dmask` is (5,3). Shouldn't our combined final mask be shaped (5,4)? What about the difference between rows, that is shaped (4,4). So, to know which entries have have horizontal partners AND vertical partners. What is the "final mask"?

Comment: Now that I think about it, your method is correct. The final matrix 'mask' should be shaped (4,3). I'm still slightly confused where the pairs are thought in this set-up....

Comment: The `argwhere` pairs are from the reduced size mask.  Mapping them on to the original array might require using index adjustments like `twodim[i, j+1]`.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure that will work either. `dmask & mask3[:,:-1]` is not the same as `dmask & mask3[:,1:]`. One you compare "from the right", the other you compare "from the left". This becomes an even greater mess for pairs diagonal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find where all three conditions are satisfied:

```
import numpy as np
twodim =  np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],  [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1, 12],  [17, 3, 15, 16], [17, 3, 18, 18]])

mask = (twodim % 2 == 0) & (twodim > 7) & (twodim % 3 =0)

print(twodim[mask])

[12 18 18]
```

Not sure what you want in the end whether all elements in the row must satisfy the condition and to find those rows or if you want individual elements.

Comment: I would love to do this. Unfortunately, as I edit above, it's difficult to create such a mask for certain conditions. The dimensions do not broadcast together properly.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: Then just slice out the overlapping parts to `&` together, or do the slicing during the creation of the masks (so `twodim[appropriate:piece] > 7`). Trying to process the `where` output is going to be much slower and more awkward.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
twodim =  np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],  [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 1, 1, 12],  [17, 3, 15, 16], [17, 3, 18, 18]])
condition = (twodim % 2. == 0.) & (twodim > 7.) & (twodim % 3. ==0.)
location = np.argwhere(condition == True) 


for i in location: 
     print i, twodim[i[0],i[1]],

>>> [2 3] 12 [4 2] 18 [4 3] 18
```